# Как правильно добавить анимацию загрузки во время работы потока. Android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-asynctask

Как правильно добавить анимацию загрузки во время работы другого потока?

Я использую AsyncTask в своем приложении. Насколько я понимаю мне нужно использовать метод onProgressUpdate в классе потока, но как с ним взаимодействовать я не знаю.
Что мне нужно сделать что бы показывать прогресс загрузки во время работы потока?

Comment: Как вам такой вариант: включаете анимацию перед началом загрузки. В момент, когда загрузка завершена, дергаете созданный ренее Handler, который выключает анимацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё зависит от того, какой именно прогресс и как вы хотите показывать.
Если вы изучали примеры работы с AsyncTask, то должны знать, что второй параметр класса это есть тип публикуемого результата, т.е. тип данных, которые будут передаваться в метод onProgressUpdate() из метода doInBackground вызовом метода publishProgress().

Ниже пример кода из [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask):

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}
```

Здесь сам AsyncTask выполняет загрузку url. Метод publishProgress передает сколько уже процентов url было загружено и в методе onProgressUpdate этот процент каким-то образом выводиться в интерфейсе.